# weird keyboard "ghosting(?)" on my Samsung Q430 laptop

Tags: linux, keyboard

I have some strange issues with my keyboard. For example:

When I press the "1" key, and then the "2" key before releasing the "1" key, the resulting output is "1\2" (instead of the exepcted ("12"). If I reverse the order I get "2\1".

If an "n" keypress overlaps with the spacebar, i get n+up key (instead of the expected "n ").

There are some other mysterious behaviors i have yet to isolate/reproduce.

It makes it very difficult to type quickly as i (like most moderately fast typists I imagine) don't always release a key before starting to press the next one.

I am running Void Linux, and I can produce these effects both in X11 and in the virtual console. These effects only occur with the internal keyboard; a USB keyboard behaves as normal, leading me to suspect a hardware issue.

Any ideas? Is this a design issue that can't be fixed, a defect that will require me to replace my keyboard, or is this some weird linux keyboard driver "feature" i can disable?

UPDATE: I booted an xubuntu USB i had lying around, and the issues were exactly the same. I suspected this would be the case but it seemed worth checking given Void's status as a "niche" distro

UPDATE: I disassembled the laptop hoping to find the keyboard ribbon connector, gave up (it was on the inaccessible-without-lots-of-work side of the mobo), and reassembled it, and now everything is back to normal??? Clearly some mechanical strain on some aspect of the keyboard has shifted. I'm obviously not very confident in this as a long term solution, and am very curious as to what the cause of this is and if there's a way to ensure this doesn't happen again.

UPDATE: nevermind, after several minutes of usage it's back.

UPDATE: I have now determined it is a thermal issue; despite cleaning the fan and repasting the heatsinks, the machine does run pretty hot, and the issue only shows up after the it's had some time to heat up. Hopefully a replacement keyboard will help, although with this model replacing the keyboard is a difficult and risky operation.

Comment: I had the same experience a number of years ago on a different setup. When you say you get 1/2, do you mean this exactly, or you get 1 or 2? What happens if you load a program or game where, say, an up and right arrow key would produce a diagonal?

Comment: i mean a 1 and a 2, separated by a backslash character. arrow keys seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the term you are looking for is keyboard **rollover**

I think this link (and the associated wiki) has your (sadly unfortunate) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662233/sdl-multiple-key-press-issue

Basically, if this answer is correct, you are looking at a hardware issue that can't be overcome at the moment. Certain gaming and "high-end" keyboards avoid this issue, but many keyboards experience it to some degree, due to the way the switches work.

I had the same thing happen to me a number of years ago, but these resources were unavailable at the time and I was doubly confused!

Comment: The difference here is that it is inserting the extraneous keystrokes, whereas the failure mode for modern (non-gaming) keyboards is supposed to be to drop any simultaneous keypresses above 3 ("blocking"/"jamming"). Also, the wiki article discusses ghosting on 3 simultaneous keypresses, whereas this behavior happens with only 2 keys. (also, see my updates)